# DataGrid Row Background Based On Cell Contains Value WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to change the background colour of DataGrid Row depending on the content of the cell? For example, the cell value contains "!"

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Opis}" Value<!-- contains-->="!">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Learn how to use `Selector`(style/template selector)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Contains` method defined in XAML so you will have to either use a converter or bind to a boolean property that uses the `string.Contains` method to determine whether the current value of `Opis` contains a specific string.

So if you add another property to the class where the `Opis` property is defined, you could bind to this one instead of binding to `Opis`, e.g.:

```
public bool Contains => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Opis) && Opis.Contains("!");
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Contains}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: `Opis` is column name in the table of DataGrid. I tried this 
 
`If Dgw3.Items.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        For i As Integer = 0 To Dgw3.Items.Count - 1
            If Dgw3.Items(i).Column("Opis").Value.ToString.Contains("!") Then
                Dgw3.Items(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Brushes.Red
           End If
        Next`  

but I get error Column on type DataRowView not found.

Comment: Why did you do this? Replace your DataTable with an IEnumerable<T> where T is a custom type that contains a property per column in the DataTable or use a converter.